# Python - Read and split every ":" and add into value

Tags: python, split

I have been playing around with reading a text file, which is currently looking like this:

```
hello:world:how:are:you
```

I am able to read it by using:

```
f = open('words.txt')
for word in f.read().split():
    print(word)
```

However, this does not split at every ":" but at every space, I believe. How can I in make it split atevery ":"?

Also when that is done. How can I etc make it work by using

```
value1 = hello
value2 = world 
value3 = how
value4 = are
value5 = you
```

and this should be reading for every ':' so it means the first word is "hello". Then, when it sees ':' it takes the second value from the text file which is "world" and adds it as a value2?

This is maybe not a good way to ask two question in one but better to have it like this than create two different threads I believe?

EDIT:

Fixed ":" by adding     `for word in f.read().split(":"):`

However now how do I take for every word into a value as I did above. So the first word to first value, second word to second value...

Comment: `.split(':')` you need to say you want to split on ":", it defaults to space

Comment: Oh god! I just tried it and that worked actually haha. Yeah well so I guess there is only one problem left now!

Comment: Why do you want the result in separate variables? Why not a list? Or dictionary?

Comment: I do not know that answer. I thought this was a easy way basically. Im kinda new into this and bsically just want to try out some stuff. Nothing special. Do you recommened List instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string 'split' function takes a seprarator as an argument (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

You might want to call the function like this:

```
value = "hello:world:how:are:you".split(":")
```

And it will give you a list of items:

```
['hello','world','how','are','you']
```

You can access them by simply using their index like this:

```
value[0] # is 'hello'
value[1] # is 'world'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I like the list solution but if you need a dict you can try this:

```
>>> words = "FOO:BAZ:BAR".split(":")
>>> words 
['FOO', 'BAZ', 'BAR']
>>> map = dict(zip(["value{}".format(x+1) for x in range(len(words))],words))
>>> map
{'value3': 'BAR', 'value2': 'BAZ', 'value1': 'FOO'}
```